# Thee or thou in these sentences:

Tags: grammar, early-modern-english

Think thee that I would desert thee? Think thee that I don't care?

or:

Think thou that I would desert thee? Think thou that I don't care?

Which one is right?

Comment: This is also proofreading.

Answer (score 2):

> Thinkest thou that I would desert thee? Thinkest thou that I don't care?

The above is the correct form.

Don't forget your conjugational ending!